# How can I avoid Chrome to suspend my app tab?

Tags: google-chrome, blazor, thread-sleep

I built a Blazor WASM app, this app reports constantly (each 30 seconds) the user activity through a Timer by calling a web api endpoint.

I need to do it this way. This is not an *X, Y problem*.

Is there a way I can programatically stop chrome from suspending my tab when the user minimizes the browser or the tab is not active? This does not happen with Firefox but most of my users use chrome.

A guy sugested me to create a PWA but it's just a browser behind so it's basically ruled by the same rules, if I'm not wrong.

If there's a specific chrome setting, I can ask my users to set it.

Or if there's another solution, like Web Workers (I'm not sure if those ain't slowed down/suspended with the tab), I would like to know.

Thanks. And if this is not the right stack to ask, please guide me, don't be rude.